# checkbox not accessible for javascript in tabpanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a checkbox and a textbox client which works good when they are not in tabpanel, but when I am putting them in a tabcontainer I am getting this error:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

That's happening when the page is trying to execute this JS code:
var chkTotalMiles = document.getElementById("<%=chkTotalMiles.ClientID %>");

I have the checkbox in ajax tabpanel, here is the code:

```
  <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Ground Transportation">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <h3>Ground Transportation</h3>
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:CheckBox Checked="false" ID="chkTotalMiles" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Miles Driven:&nbsp;</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalMiles" Enabled="false" runat="server" /></td>
<td><asp:CheckBox Checked="false" ID="chkTotalGasoline" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Gasoline Fuel Consumption:&nbsp;</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalGasoline" Enabled="false" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thanks, Laziale

Comment: What are you trying to do with it in JavaScript?

Comment: enable disable textboxes

Comment: All textboxes, or one in particular?

Comment: for each textbox there is a checkbox next to it, which enables disables the textbox. The error comes up at the first checkbox in the ajax control, so I am assuming that will be the same for all the other controls in the tab panel too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't access controls directly in the `TabContainer`, it sounds like you'll have to create the client-side code in the code-behind:

**JavaScript**

```
toggleInputEnabled = function(checkCtrl, txtCtrlID){
    var el = document.getElementById(txtCtrlID);
    if (el){
        el.disabled = !checkCtrl.checked;
    }
}
```

**Code-behind**

In the code-behind, you need to find the controls in the active tab of the `TabContainer`, and assign an `onclick` attribute to the checkbox:

```
foreach (TabPanel pnl in tbc.Tabs)
{
    var chkCtrl = pnl.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null)
    {
        var txtCtrl = pnl.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        if (txtCtrl != null)
        {        
            chkCtrl.Attributes["onclick"] = 
                String.Format("toggleInputEnabled(this, '{0}');", txtCtrl.ClientID);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with the `TabContainer`, but I think the above code should be pretty close. If only the active tab gets rendered, just remove the loop and find the controls in the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

That wording sounds like .Net wording.  I would guess that when the tab is not current, the server controls on it are not created on the server side.  Thus your attempt to access the client ID of the server control is failing.

Comment: That's not the issue. The controls in the content template are not exposed like they are in a wizard or an update panel, so you can't access them directly.